# How do I re-trigger a WebKit CSS animation via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, webkit

So, I've got this `-webkit-animation` rule:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    25% {
        left: 12px;
    }
    50% {
        left: 0;
    }
    75% {
        left: -12px;
    }
    100% {
        left:0;
    }
}
```

And some CSS defining some of the animation rules on my `box`:

```
#box{
    -webkit-animation-duration: .02s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

I can `shake` the `#box` like this:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "shake";
```

But I can't shake it again later.

This only shakes the box once:

```
someElem.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "shake";
}
```

How can I re-trigger a CSS animation via JavaScript without using timeouts or multiple animations?

Comment: is jQuery or a similar library an option?  You'd probably see better browser support.

Comment: jQuery is available but not really applicable in my case. I don't need other browser support as this will be running in Adobe Air only. I'm trying to stick with css animations instead of javascript.

Comment: Relevant: [Firmin - JavaScript animation library using CSS transforms and transitions](http://extralogical.net/projects/firmin/)

Comment: [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Comment: For all browsers: see [javascript - Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I found the answer based on the source code and examples at the [CSS3 transition tests github page](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/).

Basically, CSS animations have an `animationEnd` event that is fired when the animation completes.

For webkit browsers this event is named “`webkitAnimationEnd`”. So, in order to reset an animation after it has been called you need to add an event-listener to the element for the `animationEnd` event.

In plain vanilla javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('box');

element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
    this.style.webkitAnimationName = '';
}, false);

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    element.style.webkitAnimationName = 'shake';
    // you'll probably want to preventDefault here.
};
```

and with jQuery:

```
var $element = $('#box').bind('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
    this.style.webkitAnimationName = '';
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    $element.css('webkitAnimationName', 'shake');
    // you'll probably want to preventDefault here.
});
```

---

The source code for [CSS3 transition tests](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/) (mentioned above) has the following `support` object which may be helpful for cross-browser CSS transitions, transforms, and animations.

Here is the support code (re-formatted):

```
var css3AnimationSupport = (function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        divStyle = div.style,
        // you'll probably be better off using a `switch` instead of theses ternary ops
        support = {
            transition:
                divStyle.MozTransition     === ''? {name: 'MozTransition'   , end: 'transitionend'} :
                // Will ms add a prefix to the transitionend event?
                (divStyle.MsTransition     === ''? {name: 'MsTransition'    , end: 'msTransitionend'} :
                (divStyle.WebkitTransition === ''? {name: 'WebkitTransition', end: 'webkitTransitionEnd'} :
                (divStyle.OTransition      === ''? {name: 'OTransition'     , end: 'oTransitionEnd'} :
                (divStyle.transition       === ''? {name: 'transition'      , end: 'transitionend'} :
                false)))),
            transform:
                divStyle.MozTransform     === '' ? 'MozTransform'    :
                (divStyle.MsTransform     === '' ? 'MsTransform'     :
                (divStyle.WebkitTransform === '' ? 'WebkitTransform' : 
                (divStyle.OTransform      === '' ? 'OTransform'      :
                (divStyle.transform       === '' ? 'transform'       :
                false))))
            //, animation: ...
        };
    support.transformProp = support.transform.name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
    return support;
}());
```

I have not added the code to detect “animation” properties for each browser. I’ve made this answer “community wiki” and leave that to you.  :-)

Comment: the cited source code has been moved to https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/

Comment: Note: the code in the github repo has changed since this answer; the code there and the code here are completely different now.

Comment: Note that if there is an CSS rule that assigns the animation to the object, setting it to `''` would make it inherit from the CSS rule, in that case it's necessary to set it to `none`.

Answer (score 14):

You have to first *remove* the animation, then add it again.  Eg:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
setTimeout(function ()
{
    document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "shake";
}, 0);
```

To do this without setTimeout remove the animation during `onmousedown`, and add it during `onclick`:

```
someElem.onmousedown = function()
{
    document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
}
someElem.onclick = function()
{
    document.getElementById("box").style.webkitAnimationName = "shake";
}
```

Comment: Yah, this is the same as what I came up with. But I'd like to do without the setTimeout if possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative that does not use setTimeout.

Answer (score 8):

Following the suggestion from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Tips, remove and then add the animation class, using requestAnimationFrame to ensure that the rendering engine processes both changes.  I think this is cleaner than using setTimeout, and handles replaying an animation before the previous play has completed.

```
$('#shake-the-box').click(function(){   
  $('#box').removeClass("trigger");
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(time) {
      $('#box').addClass("trigger");
    });
    });
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/gcmwyr14/5/

Answer (score 6):

A simple but effective alternative:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="shake-the-box">Shake it!</button>​
```

css:

```
#box{
    background: blue;
    margin:30px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-animation:shake .2s 0 linear 1; 
    -webkit-animation:shake .2s 0 linear 1; 
}
#box.trigger{
    display:table;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    25% {
        left: 12px;
    }
    50% {
        left: 0;
    }
    75% {
        left: -12px;
    }
    100% {
        left:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    25% {
        left: 12px;
    }
    50% {
        left: 0;
    }
    75% {
        left: -12px;
    }
    100% {
        left:0;
    }
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#shake-the-box').click(function(){

  $('#box').toggleClass('trigger');

});​
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/5832R/2/

Issues:
I don't know if it works on Firefox, because the animation doesn't seem to work there...

Comment: This works, but for some reason the overflow rule is ignored..I have it set to hidden but after the animation overflow shows

Answer (score 3):

Reset the value first. Use reflow to apply the change without using timeout:

```js
function shake() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  box.style.animationName = null;
  box.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
  box.style.animationName = "shake";
}
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
    0% { left: 0; }
   25% { left: 12px; }
   50% { left: 0; }
   75% { left: -12px; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px; height: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    animation-duration: .02s;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="shake()">Shake</button>
```

In contrast to the accepted answer that recommends `animationEnd`, this method resets the animation even when it's still in progress. This might be or might be not what you want.

---

An alternative would be to create a duplicate `@keyframes` animation and switch between the two:

```js
function shake() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  if (box.style.animationName === "shake")
      box.style.animationName = "shake2";
  else
      box.style.animationName = "shake";
}
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
    0% { left: 0; }
   25% { left: 12px; }
   50% { left: 0; }
   75% { left: -12px; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes shake2 {
    0% { left: 0; }
   25% { left: 12px; }
   50% { left: 0; }
   75% { left: -12px; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px; height: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    animation-duration: .02s;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="shake()">Shake</button>
```

Comment: note: per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664940/force-browser-to-trigger-reflow-while-changing-css, it may be better to use e.g. `void( box.offsetHeight);` instead, because statement with var access and with no effect may be optimized out (and will trigger linters to emit warnings like `Unexpected expression '.' in statement position.` - courtesy of JSLint)

Comment: also, note that reflows are quite "heavy" (computationally intensive) operations.

Answer (score 2):

Clone works pretty good on paused Karaoke:
On IE11 had to force a reflow (R. Krupiński's shorter version).

```
$('#lyrics').text("Why does it hurt when I pee?");
changeLyrics('3s');  

function changeLyrics(sec) {
  str = 'lyrics '+ sec + ' linear 1';
  $('#lyrics').css( 'animation', str);
  $('#lyrics').css( 'animation-play-state', 'running' );
  $('#lyrics').replaceWith($('#lyrics').clone(true)); 
}
```

or you can use the following:

```
function resetAnimation(elm) {
  $('#'+elm).replaceWith($('#'+elm).clone(true)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue with using `setTimeout()` to remove the class and then read it 5ms later?

```
svg.classList.remove('animate');
setTimeout(function() {
  svg.classList.add('animate');
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

With your javascript, you could also add (and then remove) a CSS class in which the animation is declared. See what I mean ?

```
#cart p.anim {
  animation: demo 1s 1; // Fire once the "demo" animation which last 1s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add animation name to the `#box.trigger` in css

```
#box.trigger{
    display:table;
    animation:shake .2s 0 linear 1;
    -moz-animation:shake .2s 0 linear 1; 
    -webkit-animation:shake .2s 0 linear 1;
}
```

2) In java-script you cannot remove the class `trigger`.

3) Remove the the class name by using `setTimeOut` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shake-the-box').click(function(){

    $('#box').addClass('trigger');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#box").removeClass("trigger")},500)        
    });
});
```

4) Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5832R/213/).