# Why do browsers use prefixes?

Tags: browser, css, webkit, prefix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do browsers create vendor prefixes for CSS properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131846/why-do-browsers-create-vendor-prefixes-for-css-properties)

What is the advantage for browsers to use prefixes to implement some technology?

e.g. Google Chrome needs the -webkit- prefix to render some css3-tags, like animation (it needs "-webkit-animation:" to work).

What is the advantage compared to implementing the technique directly into chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers use prefixes so that they can implement a new features before it gets standardized.

Comment: But a browser does not have to use the standards, anything can be implemented in a browser, that's up to the programmers. So why use prefix implementation instead of ordinary implementation (why would non-standard implementations hurt?)