# How to show full text on hover but after some delay using CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to show full text on cursor hover but only after 1s delay. I tried adding `transition` property but it seems it doesn't apply to `absolute` elements. Here's the [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/jerrygoyal/pen/ZEpdqqd).
Here's the code:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main .parent:hover .cell {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: gray;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.main .parent {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(237, 237, 236);
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-height: 32px;
  cursor: default;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 8px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main .parent .cell {
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-break: normal;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="cell">
      In publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text
      commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface
      without relying on meaningful content.</span
    >
  </div>
</main>
```

Notice that background color is transiting properly but the full text is shown instantly as soon as I hover.

Looking for a solution to add some delay in showing full text without using any JavaScript.

Comment: Is this something you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089444/how-to-change-text-color-with-css-transitions

Comment: no, that question is about changing color i'm asking about adding delay while showing full text on hover.

Comment: Which property are you using to display the text? z-index, overflow?

Comment: "that question is about changing color"; so... swap color with with property you want to transition. You've not specified any property to transition (a `transition-property`); that's why it's not transitioning currently (you specified the delay only).

Comment: It looks like you're using the `overflow` property to reveal the text - which is a property assigned to the container, not the text. Have you tried putting a hover on the container?

Comment: i tried mentioned approaches but nothing worked. i might be missing something so can you share some working snippet. here's the starting point demo https://codepen.io/jerrygoyal/pen/ZEpdqqd

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it work by using css `animation`. Working [codepan demo](https://codepen.io/jerrygoyal/pen/abmeNjz)

```css
@keyframes hover-delay {
  0%   {
    background: gray;
    position:absolute;
  }
  100% {
    background: gray;
  position: absolute ;}
}

 .parent {
    &:hover {
      .cell {
        z-index: 1 !important;
        padding-right: 10px;
        animation-name : hover-delay;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        // animation-iteration-count: infinite; // play animation infinite times
        
        // alternate way: retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
    }
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(237, 237, 236);
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-height: 32px;
    cursor: default;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 5px 8px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;

    .cell {
      line-height: 1.5;
      white-space: nowrap;
      word-break: normal;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Works for me, even with `position:absolute;`

But I went ahead and included a version that uses animation (transition too)

https://jsfiddle.net/56sxzcu7/

```
/* Using transition */

h1 {
  transition:1s;
  transition-delay:1s;
  opacity:1;
  position:absolute;
}

h1:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* Using animate */

h2:hover {
  animation: example 2s linear 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0.5;}
}
```

Comment: this absolutely works for me - glad you got it working though