# What does it mean when a css rule starts with an @

Tags: css

For example

`@-moz-keyframes shake {     0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}   10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);} }`

what is `@`? I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291483/what-does-it-mean-when-a-css-property-starts-with-a-dash)  `-` signifies a vendor prefix and the `@` always seems to precede this.

Comment: RTLM: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#at-rules

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/At-rule

Comment: @MarcB out of curiosity what does RTLM stand for?

Comment: RTLM is the family friendly version of "RTFM".