# css styles, purpose of webkit

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying wrap my head around as to exactly what webkit means when it comes to styles.  For example I have the following

```
div {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotateY(60deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

What is the purpose of attributes with "webkit", even if I remove them this still works fine on Chrome.  If "webkit" is for Chrome, Safari, and Opera are the other tags for non-webkit like IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Why do browsers create vendor prefixes for CSS properties?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131846/why-do-browsers-create-vendor-prefixes-for-css-properties) They also provide backwards compatibility if someone has an old version of Chrome, FF etc. Decide what level of browser support you need and based on that you'll know if you need to use vendor prefixes. [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com) is a great resource to find out when you might need to use a vendor prefix or not.

Comment: Before CSS functions get normalized there is the stage in which browser manufacturers are developing and implementing their new functionality. You can see it as a prototype, so functionalities that are not yet officially launched under W3C. After functions get normalized the prefix may be omitted. A good source to determine what you should do is the site http://caniuse.com/. Some folk use prefix consistently without questioning if they have to. What is also seen is that they use a library that takes care of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do browsers create vendor prefixes for CSS properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131846/why-do-browsers-create-vendor-prefixes-for-css-properties)