# What does -webkit- mean as in -webkit-transition?

Tags: css

What does `-webkit-` mean as in `-webkit-transition`, `-webkit-transform`, etc. What is its function? Why do i have to use `-webkit-transition` and `transition` together instead of just using `transition`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do browsers create vendor prefixes for CSS properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131846/why-do-browsers-create-vendor-prefixes-for-css-properties) or [What are -moz- and -webkit-?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/what-are-moz-and-webkit)

Comment: some times safari browser not accept normal css code. that's why we add -webkit-

Answer (score 1):

The -webkit- prefix is a vendor prefix, there are other prefixes viz; -moz-, -o-, and -ms-. Most times, you will need to use all other vendor prefixes whenever you need to use the -webkit- prefix.

This prefixes represent the major CSS parsers used by web browsers. Where moz- represents Mozilla based parsing engine, o- for opera, -ms- for Microsoft, and webkit for webkit based browsers like Google chrome and safari.

That said, vendor prefixes are attached to new CSS rules that are not yet fully supported by the target vendor (browser). This properties are already usable by this browsers, but let's say they are currently locked, and you can unlock them using the browser's prefix.