# CSS3 & Jquery Animation - Repeat after some seconds

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have created a css3 animation following like this

http://jsfiddle.net/WXHjN/

I am using the following Jquery to control time interval

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').addClass("fadeInLeft");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#development').addClass("fadeInLeft");
    },300)
});
```

In the above example the animation happening at once only. 
I need this animation to repeat after some seconds. Also it must be repeat at infinity times.

Comment: You need to remove the class at some point, or else you are not adding anything, therefore no animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try below logic

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateItems();
});

var animationRef;

function animateItems()
{
    $('#web').removeClass("fadeInLeft");
    $('#development').removeClass("fadeInLeft");

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#web').addClass("fadeInLeft");},300);

  window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#development').addClass ("fadeInLeft");
  },600);

     animationRef = window.setTimeout(animateItems,2000);
};
```

The logic says remove fadeInLeft class and setTimeout to execute function that displays text.

I have stored reference of timeout in animationRef variable to clear timeout, which should not be used in your code.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WXHjN/6/)

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050914/css-animation-doesnt-restart-when-resetting-class.  And though the solutions here don't quite do it, this blog points out the issues with resetting the animation.  http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

[Demo: fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bharathi/WXHjN/2/)