# Toggling a CSS3 animation on click

Tags: css, animation, toggle, reverse, css-animations

What is the best way to alternate the direction of a CSS3 animation on click without javascript?

I've been exploring checkbox hacks lately and trying to figure out a way to have only one set of keyframes instead of two sets for one going forward and one to come back. Is this possible? Or is there a way to do it with one set?

For instance I have the following keyframes:

```
@keyframes moveIt {
  0%   { 
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: $size;
  }
  50%  {
    width: $size*1.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
    width: $size;
  }
}
@keyframes moveItBack {
  100%   { 
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: $size;
  }
  50%  {
    width: $size*1.2;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
    width: $size;
  }
}
```

Any way to reduce this to only the first set? Then when coming back start from 100% and go back to 0%?

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/ftntravis/pen/hpAye) of what I am trying to accomplish this on.

Comment: I've used a variation on the checkbox hack, with two radio buttons (each with its own label) and two mirror-image animations. Cumbersome, but completely effective. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5cnsn38L/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS is not really meant to do something like this but there are some work-arounds

Optimally we could do something like the following because it makes sense logically

```
.bubble {
  ...
  animation: moveIt .25s forwards ease-out;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .bubble {
  animation: moveIt .25s backwards ease-out;
}
```

However, you cannot reset or change to a different animation using pure CSS<sup>[1]</sup>. This is because elements are only allowed to have one animation each. You can [reset it in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6303311/2065702) by using `setTimeout` or cloning the element, but I assume you're trying to avoid that.

Thus, you're left with two options. The first is to ditch the change in size and just toggle the `translateX` [like so](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsoqa):

```
.bubble {
  ...
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .bubble {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

The other option to retain the change in size is to do something a bit more involved. You can essentially fake the change of size by using pseudo elements. By toggling the animation of both opposite from each other, you can make the whole element look like it pulses each time. [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezxLy)

```
.bubble {
  ...
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
.bubble:after, .bubble:before {
  content:''; 
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  animation:'';
}
.bubble:before { animation:size .25s ease-out; }
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .bubble:before { animation:''; }
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .bubble {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .bubble:after {
  animation:size .25s ease-out;
}
@keyframes size {
  50% { transform:scale(1.2); }
}
```

I hope it makes sense!

<sup>[1]</sup>: As seen in the second option, it is *possible*, it just requires a state of removing the past animation. Sadly something like `animation:''; animation:moveIt .25s backwards ease-out;` does not reset it

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer! Thanks for clarifying things as well as fixing my question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same, just double the duration.

```
@keyframes moveIt {
  0%   { 
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: $size;
  }
  25% {
    width: $size*1.2;
  }
  50%  {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  75% {
    width: $size*1.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: $size;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. I would like to be able to toggle this state and come back from it. So not all at once, but toggle the first animation, then toggle it again and reverse back.