# How to restart CSS Animation with minimal impact

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Is there a way to restart a CSS animation without cloning elements, reflowing DOM, waiting (setTimeout/onAnimationEnd)?

Comment: @freedomn-m of course not, see the word *"like"*

Comment: @freedomn-m not really, since it can be used in every actual "restarting animation" scenarios

Comment: What's the case where a `setTimeout` is undesirable?

Answer (score 11):

*EDIT:* No jQuery or check needed.

I basically just restart the animation at the next painted frame.

This method doesn't clone any element, reflows the document, setting any timeout, or waiting for completion of the animation.
It is 100% flexible and requires no jQuery.

I haven't seen anything similar (not even at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)) so I wanted to share my idea with you and hear your thoughts.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe)

```js
document.querySelector('.box').onclick = function(){
  requestAnimation( this );
};

var requestAnimation = function( obj ){
  obj.style.animation = 'none';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    obj.style.animation = 'myAnimation 1s';
  });
}
```

```css
html{ background: #212121; }

.box{
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
span{
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}
@keyframes myAnimation{
  from{ background: grey; transform: scale(1.2); }
  to{ background: white; transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">I can animate forever!</div>
<span>By Luca Rossi</span>
```

Comment: can you post the same function in pure javascript

Comment: @vikrant pure javascript, no check for state needed!

Comment: I will try to use this method in my project

Comment: I will observe whether there will be some disadvantages.

Comment: Works great on PC. Not so much on Android Vivaldi

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most reliable way to "restart" CSS animations I've found is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525340/3705191

##### TL;DR: *switch between two identical keyframe animations*

---

##### Here's the gist of it:

1. Create 2 **identical keyframe declarations** (e.g. `animation1` and `animation2`)
2. Assign *one of them* to your desired element's `animation` property
3. When wanting to restart, check the name of the animation keyframes the element currently has, and then switch over to the other keyframes name

   - *this can be achieved in various ways, but it's the **switching** that's essential*

##### Example

```css
@keyframes popup1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes popup2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```css
.animated-element {
  animation: popup1 200ms ease;
}
```

```js
// when wanting to restart:
const el = document.$('.animated-element');

// animationName only returns the name
if( el.style.animationName == 'popup1' ){
  el.style.animation = 'popup2 200ms ease';
} else {
  el.style.animation = 'popup1 200ms ease';
}
```