# Fading background image with javascript on image switch

Tags: javascript

I have three images which my two div's switch between. However, the animation appears too rough. How do I apply a fade right before the switch?

```
<div class="my-images">
   <div id="image-1"></div>
   <div id="image-2"></div>
</div>


<script>
  function displayNextImage() {
     x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
     document.getElementById("image-1").style.backgroundImage = images[x];
     document.getElementById("image-2").style.backgroundImage = images[x];
  }

  function startTimer() {
     setInterval(displayNextImage, 10000);
  }

  var images = [],
  x = 0;
  images[0] = "url('images/snow.jpeg')";
  images[1] = "url('images/nike.jpeg')";
  images[2] = "url('images/motor.jpeg')";
</script>
```

This loops continuously so I do not want it just fading in on the first load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JQuery you'll have cross-browser compatibility issue.
So i suggest you to use JQuery to achieve this.

```
<div class="my-images">
   <div class="my-image" id="image-1"></div>
   <div class="my-image" id="image-2"></div>
</div>


<script>
  function displayNextImage() {
    $("#image-" + x).css('backgroundImage',  images[x]).show('slow');
    x++;
  }

  var images = [],
  x = 0;
  images[0] = "url('images/snow.jpeg')";
  images[1] = "url('images/nike.jpeg')";
  images[2] = "url('images/motor.jpeg')";
</script>
```

And you have to add this to css:

```
.my-image{
  display:none;
}
```

In case you not use `display: block` to you element:
Your CSS will be:

```
.my-image{
  display:whatYouWant;
}
```

Then need add the document `ready()` function and change `show()` to `fadeIn()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my-image").hide();
  });

  function displayNextImage() {
    $("#image-" + x).css('backgroundImage',  images[x]).fadeIn('slow');
    x++;
  }
```

This will work because `fadeIn()` set to display the previous value.

If you want div visible before image adding, remove `$(document).ready()` call and edit `displayNextImage()`:

```
function displayNextImage() {
  $("#image-" + x).hide().css('backgroundImage',  images[x]).fadeIn('slow');
  x++;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you did but on load it makes the divs dissapear then reappear after the timer with the new image. I do not want the divs to dissapear on load.

Comment: On load the div is still missing and this only fades slow the first time after that it doesn't anymore then it just changes the pictures. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Ops, I didn't understand you want visible divs before images, I edited answer again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS animation, for each cycle:

1) swap the image sources like you are already doing

2) reset the fade in animation, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element)

3) increment your index

```js
const imgs = [
  'https://source.unsplash.com/iMdsjoiftZo/100x100',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/ifhgv-c6QiY/100x100',
  'https://source.unsplash.com/w5e288LU8SU/100x100'
];

let index = 0;

const oldImage1 = document.getElementById('oldImage1');
const newImage1 = document.getElementById('newImage1');
const oldImage2 = document.getElementById('oldImage2');
const newImage2 = document.getElementById('newImage2');

window.setInterval(() => {
  // put new image in old image
  oldImage1.src = newImage1.src;
  oldImage2.src = newImage2.src;
  
  // Set new image
  newImage1.src = imgs[index];
  newImage2.src = imgs[index];
  
  // reset animation
  newImage1.style.animation = 'none';
  newImage1.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
  newImage1.style.animation = null; 
  newImage2.style.animation = 'none';
  newImage2.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
  newImage2.style.animation = null; 
  
  // increment x
  index = index + 1 >= imgs.length ? 0 : index + 1;
}, 1500);
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}

.oldImage1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.newImage1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.oldImage2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 100;
}

.newImage2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img id="oldImage1" class="oldImage1" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ifhgv-c6QiY/100x100" />
  <img id="newImage1" class="newImage1 fade-in" src="https://source.unsplash.com/w5e288LU8SU/100x100" />
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <img id="oldImage2" class="oldImage2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ifhgv-c6QiY/100x100" />
  <img id="newImage2" class="newImage2 fade-in" src="https://source.unsplash.com/w5e288LU8SU/100x100" />
</div>
```