# I want to repeat mouseover function on animated icon

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make animated icon to be playable every time on hover instead of just once. But I cant make it work with `mouseout` There is my code:

```
<div class="shapeshifter" id='btn' style="background-image: 
url(sprite_60fps.svg) "></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mouseover', 
    function() {
    this.classList.add('play');
}); 

 </script>
```

Comment: You might want to remove the `play` class when a `mouseout` event occurs. That way the class will be added again on `mouseover` and the animation will start again.

Comment: I should  place the same script, but with `mouseout`, and with what I have to change  the `play`?

Comment: Yeah basically the same as you have here except using `this.classList.remove('play')` instead.

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.classList.add('play');
 });  
 
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {  
 });`

Comment: This doesn't work :/

Comment: @ВалериК. - Your `mouseout` event's callback is empty.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is "restart css animation with js on mouse enter".

call this function on mouse enter:

```
function reset_animation() {
  var el = document.getElementById('btn');
  el.style.animation = 'none';
  el.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
  el.style.animation = null; 
}
```

make sure don't use it on mouseover, use it on mouseenter.

(more info: [Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element))

Comment: I want animation to play just once on hover, and when I come back on in to repeat again once. When I do the iteration it repeats nonstop until I mouseleave