# Animation not playing for the second time

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have an easy password box shake animation when the password is wrong but it doesn't play for the second time when I enter the wrong password. My logic is the following:

```js
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordbox")
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox")
    var submittedPassword = password.value;
    
    if( submittedPassword == "abc"){
        
        location.href = "secret.html"
    }
    if(submittedPassword !== "abc"){
       checkbox.checked = false
       document.getElementById("passwordbox").style.animation = "shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both"    
    }
}
```

This is my css animation:

```css
@keyframes shake {
    8%, 41% {
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    25%, 58% {
        transform: translateX(10px);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    92% {
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element

Comment: Just an observation, I assume this is just a little exercise and not code going into production site as it is not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! my JS code looks like this now

```
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordbox")
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox")
    var submittedPassword = password.value;
    
    if( submittedPassword == "abc"){
        
        location.href = "secret.html"
    }
    if(submittedPassword !== "abc"){
        document.getElementById("passwordbox").style.animation = "shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both";
        checkbox.checked = false
        document.getElementById('passwordbox').addEventListener("animationend" ,function restart(){document.getElementById("passwordbox").style.animation = "";})    
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are never removing the animation. You will want to remove it every time before you play the animation so it will play more than once. You can use the following code:

```js
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordbox")
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox")
    var submittedPassword = password.value;
    
    if( submittedPassword == "abc"){
        
        location.href = "secret.html"
    }
    if(submittedPassword !== "abc"){
       document.getElementById("passwordbox").style.animation = "";
       checkbox.checked = false
       document.getElementById("passwordbox").style.animation = "shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both"    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't seem to work. If it helps ,I call the passwordcheck function in this HTML code: `<input type="checkbox" onclick="passwordCheck()" id = "checkbox">`