# Why doesn't a CSS transition to opacity work on a div inside <details>?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple accordion with transitions to make the opening/closing smooth. I also want the text within the accordion tab to fade in/out, but for some reason the CSS transition isn't applying and I can't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
details {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

details summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin 150ms ease-out;
}

details div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

details[open] summary {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

details[open] div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
```

Comment: it seems to be a chrome bug, works fine on FIrefox

Comment: Oh I think its a webkit bug as its not working in safari either. Any ideas on how to get around it?

Comment: When I open inspect element box in chrome and click on accordion transition work might be a height issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use !Important  at your CSS Code, I've tried code that was previously unreadable, after using !Important CSS code can be read well.  hope it can help you

Answer (score -1):

Use keyframe instead

```css
details {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

details summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin 150ms ease-out;
}

details[open] summary {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

details[open] div {
  animation: sweep .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0; margin-left: -10px}
  100%  {opacity: 1; margin-left: 0px}
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.</div>
</details>
```

Comment: Now that closes the circle to their previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867127/do-css-keyframe-animations-require-js-to-run-more-than-once ... why the animation appears to work only once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to avoid keyframes because they only run once. If you open the accordion tab more than once, no animation applies.