# Angular: Keyframe animation not working with ngClass

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an animation that makes the text scale up and back down when a variable changes.  Instead of using angular's animation module I'm trying to achieve this with plain css and the `ngClass` directive.  Seeing that I want the same animation to run whenever the value changes I created 2 classes that have the same `@keyframes` animation initially assuming as the classes switched it would run.  However this is not the case and I can't figure out how to get it working.  [Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-re5fez?file=src%2Fmain.css) of a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, the code looks like this.

**component**

```
export class App {
  AnimationToggle: boolean = false;

  toggler(): void {
    this.AnimationToggle = !this.AnimationToggle;
    console.log(this.AnimationToggle);
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<button type="button" (click)="toggler()">trigger</button>

<p class="textDemo"
  [ngClass]="AnimationToggle ? 'toggleA': 'toggleB'"
>
  Some Text
</p>
```

**styling**

```
.textDemo{
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.toggleA, .toggleB{
  animation-name: toggleAnimation;
}

@keyframes toggleAnimation{
  0%,
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  70%{
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  95%{
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

The only thing I could think to do is duplicate the keyframe animation and name them `animationToggleA` and `AnimationToggleB` and apply them to the `toggleA` and `toggleB` classes separately however that didn't make a difference.  Does anybody know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described here (this also applies to angular) [Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element)

so you can try some of solutions from this article, for example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="toggler()">trigger</button>

    <p class="textDemo"
      [ngClass]="elClass">
      Some Text
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./main.css'],
})
export class App {
  public elClass = 'anima';

  toggler(): void {
    this.elClass = '';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.elClass = 'anima';
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

css

```
.anima{
  animation: toggleAnimation 1s ease;
}

@keyframes toggleAnimation{
  0%,
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  70%{
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  95%{
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```