# Set CSS animation direction based on data-attribute with single CSS animation

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I am using framer motion to trigger a data state attribute based on the scroll point inside a container.

If the data state attribute is forward, I want the css animation to go forward, and if the data state attribute is reverse, I want the animation to reverse. I have it working, but I have to define two separate indentical css animations with different animation directions for it to work. If i just change the animation-direction in each data state attribute, it only toggles between the end animation states when crossing the scroll point, it doesn't animate between them.

Is there a way to animate forward or reverse with a single css animation based on a data state attribute?

[Codesandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-css-animation-qht3kt?file=/src/styles.scss)

Comment: You're correct in your assertion that setting `animation-direction:reverse;` does not reset the progress of the animation. It will just continue at whatever % it was, generally at 100%. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element) explores way to reset the animation. Though personally, I would also opt to having 2 distinct animations and toggle between that.  Look into using [transition](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-css-animation-forked-qqyh82?file=/src/styles.scss) instead if it's a basic animation.

Comment: As @Lars said, in this case you should be using transition, it is just a simple change in values