# How to Sync CSS3 Animation Events and Event Listeners with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to figure out a solid, cross-(modern)browser method for using **CSS3 Animation Events** and Event Listeners to gain fine-tuned control over CSS3 animations. I know its possible to do this. Sadly it's just WAY beyond my capabilities at the moment, despite all the research I've done in the last 2-3 weeks.

Here is my jsfiddle on this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mvkMH/23/

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I have a `<ul>` with an id of `#main` containing `<li>`'s with a class of `.box`. When a user clicks on any `.box` it adds the `.move-y` class to `($this)` - it also simultaneously adds the `.move-x` class to the remaining list items. When the user clicks another `.box`, all the existing `.move-y and .move-x` classes are replaced with `.move-y-rvs and .move-x-rvs` classes. All the while using CSS3 Animation events to keep everything perfectly synced up.

**Why CSS3 Animation Events?**

- CSS3 Animations are fast on iOS
- CSS3 Animation triggered via jQuery allow you to 'restart' the animation if it has been played already (https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)
- In theory, by using jQuery to keep track of **AnimationStart**, **AnimationIteration** and **AnimationEnd** events one can create very complex and interactive CSS3 animations.

Here is the way the script should work in my mind - I just couldn't get it to work in real life ;-)

1. Upon clicking the .box element, Check #main for any .move-x and .move-y classes
2. If .move-x and .move-y classes are detected:

   - replace those classes with move-x-rvs and .move-y-rvs
   - Attach css **Animation Event** listeners to the elements with .move-x-rvs and .move-y-rvs classes
   - On **AnimationEnd Event** remove the .move-x-rvs and .move-y-rvs classes
   - Set **AnimationName** to an empty string (this resets the css3 animation to play again if clicked again)
   - Now add the .move-y class to $(this)
   - Add the .move-x class to all the other remaining list items
3. If .move-x and .move-y are not detected:

   - Add the .move-y class to $(this)
   - Add the .move-x class to all the other remaining list items

4 - The **Animation Event** listener functionality should append the prefixes for modern browsers (like in this example - [How do I re-trigger a WebKit CSS animation via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript))

Again, Here is my jsfiddle on this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mvkMH/23/

Any help you folks could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
Bizarro.Z

Comment: `$mbox` is not defined error in your fiddle?

Comment: quite old but I came along here....just fixed errors in your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mvkMH/82/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

create a jQuery function that changes the class of an element with a specific ID.
Then you can sync them by calling the function in the jQuery code.