# jquery html5 webkit-animation callback

Tags: jquery, html, webkit, callback, webkit-animation

Is there any callback on webkit-animation complete? see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jgb8h/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.animate {
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}​

$("div").bind("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
  alert(1);
}).addClass("animate");​
```

But this callback doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, it seems this works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition

Comment: I have read alot of documentation about it, and came over certain projects where somebody said its possible some say its not. I found the mozilla documentation for transitions  which said its possible https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

Comment: google chrome 17.0.963.46 beta - this doesn't work because there are no transition in webkit-keyframes. question is about webkit-animation. I dont know what noob invented this css3 & html5 without javascript callbacks. I am confused

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I re-trigger a WebKit CSS animation via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript)

Comment: You want the `webkitAnimationEnd` event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

`element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(event) {  });`

in firefox the event is called 'animationend', but some webkit browsers will listen to both of these. Instead what you can do if you use jquery is to use

`$element.on('webkitAnimationEnd animationend' , function(event){   });`

---

Update:

I recently had a small mishap using `.one('webkitAnimationEnd animationend')` since both events are being listened to in chrome, but only one fired at a time, the same function will fire twice on two seperate animation end events.

Instead a small trick could be using a function similar to this:

```
getTransitionEndEvent : function(){
    switch(this._currentBrowser){
        case enums.Browser.SAFARI:
        case enums.Browser.CHROME:
            return "webkitTransitionEnd";
        case enums.Browser.FIREFOX:
            return "transitionend";
        default:
            console.log("unknown browser agent for transition end event");
            return "";
    }
}
```

and add more vendor specific prefixes as needed.

In order to identify the browser I can really recommend this:

[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)