# Trouble re-triggering CSS 3 animation after Ajax response

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, animation, dom-events

Here is an HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="camount.php" id="loginForm">
  <span id="heading">
    Username: <input type="text" name='us' id='us'/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name='pa' id='pa'/><br />
  </span>
  <input type="button" value="Sign in" onclick="isPasswordCorrect(document.getElementById('us'), document.getElementById('pa'))" /><br />
  <span class="animated shake" id="report"></span>
</form>
```

Here is the relevant code of the JavaScript function that is called

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
  if(xmlhttp.responseText)
    document.getElementById("loginForm").submit()
  else{ 
    document.getElementById("report").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
    setTimeout(function (){
    document.getElementById("report").style.webkitAnimationName="animated shake";
    }, 0);
    var element = document.getElementById('report');
    element.innerHTML = "wrong password/username"   
    password.value = ""
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("post", "CheckCred.php", true)
//required for sending data through POST
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name.value)+
             "&password="+encodeURIComponent(password.value))
```

Here is the CSS that is supposed to make the text in the `<span>` tag appear in red and shake. It does appear in red, it does not shake.

```
.animated{
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  -ms-animation-duration:1s;
  -o-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}
.animated.hinge{
  -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
  -moz-animation-duration:2s;
  -ms-animation-duration:2s;
  -o-animation-duration:2s;
  animation-duration:2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}
  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes shake{
  0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}
  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);}
}
@-o-keyframes shake{
  0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0);}
  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateX(-10px);}
  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateX(10px);}
}
@keyframes shake{
  0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}
  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}
  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);}
}    
.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  -moz-animation-name: shake;
  -o-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}    
span#report{
    display: block;
    color: #F80000;
}
```

I've been trying to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript) to no avail. I would like this to work in FireFox. Can any one give me any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong and why the text "wrong username/password" won't shake?

As per MarZab's suggestion I tried

```
document.getElementById("report").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
setTimeout(function (){
  document.getElementById("report").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
  document.getElementById("report").style.webkitAnimationName = "animated shake";
}, 4);
```

and it still doesn't shake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `className` instead of `webkitAnimationName`

http://jsfiddle.net/5832R/99/

as discused in chat, the real issue was `execution line`

browsers tend to only change the state of the DOM after executing code
and since the class remained the same inside the same execution code, the animation was not retrigered.

putting the unset in another execution line, ie. outside of the request, forced the DOM to change

the valid code is:

```
function isPasswordCorrect(name, password) 
{ 
  report.className = ""; 

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  { 
    report = document.getElementById('report'); 
    report.className = "animated shake"; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Still no. If you like up-vote the question so it gets more attention.

Comment: Where did you want me to add the code anyways, right before `element.innerHTML = "wrong password/username"`? Did you expect me to remove the code regarding the timeout?

Comment: you should replace/add this inside the timeout. why do you have a timeout 0 anyway?

Comment: For the timeout I'm trying to follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript) and that is what they have. I don't really understand it, if you can explain it that would be great thanks.

Comment: So I copied and pasted your code and it doesn't work for me. I know it works in jsfiddle. I can't imagine what is doing this.

Comment: Hmm I've only got it locally on my computer, is there a program I can use to show you what I see? i.e. TeamViewer...oh wait on SO there's no private messaging so I wouldn't be able to give you the log in details :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30161/discussion-between-marzab-and-celeritas)