# css3 animation on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I need to animate several items at the same time, several times on click. I'm not allowed to use Jquery so I'm working with native javascript and CSS3.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    elemId = el.getAttribute("id");

    var toWidth = boxPos[thisId][elemId].width;
    var toHeight = boxPos[thisId][elemId].height;
    var toTop = boxPos[thisId][elemId].top;
    var toLeft = boxPos[thisId][elemId].left;           
    var from = "0% {width:"+currPos[elemId].width+"; height:"+currPos[elemId].height+"; top:"+currPos[elemId].top+"; left:"+currPos[elemId].left+";}";
    var to = "100% { width:"+toWidth+"; height:"+toHeight+"; top:"+toTop+"; left:"+toLeft+";}";
    currPos[elemId].width = toWidth;
    currPos[elemId].height = toHeight;
    currPos[elemId].top = toTop;
    currPos[elemId].left = toLeft;

    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            if (styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE && styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].name == elemId){
                keyframes = styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];

            }
        }
    }
    keyframes.deleteRule("0%");
    keyframes.deleteRule("100%");

    keyframes.insertRule(from);
    keyframes.insertRule(to);
    el.style.webkitAnimationName = elemId;
});
```

I've searched around the site and have tried using some of the code. The animation will run once, all the elements but just the first time  :'(

Here's a non working example code http://jsfiddle.net/kR384/2/

Comment: Please also show us how you are attaching the click handlers and how the click handler invokes this animation.

Comment: hey @Bergi, just added the full code, only the 10 and 7 box is clickable, I should be able to click one after the other the animation just runs once

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [How do I re-trigger a WebKit CSS animation via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The animation will run once, all the elements but just the first time

You seem to be looking for the [`animation-iteration-count` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count), which specifies how often an animation will run. You can set it to `infinite` or any numerical (positive) value.

---

The problem you have with your animations is that they are only started on the first click. After that, you don't change the element's styles (reassigning the `animation-name` doesn't help) - so no animation will get triggered (even if you changed the keyframes rules). The article at http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/ discusses this and a few solutions.

In your case it would even make sense to change the name of animation to something containing the "state":

```
     if( …cssRules[j].name.split("-")[0] == elemId)
         keyframes = styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];
…


var newname = elemId+"-"+thisId;
keyframes.name = newname;
…
el.style.animationName = newname;
```

([Demo with standard properties and a few bugfixes](http://jsfiddle.net/kR384/4/), [updated demo with `webkit` prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/kR384/5/))

Comment: actually I have the animation set to -webkit-animation:all 0.5s forwards;. I'm afraid that if I set it to infinite the first round of animations will just loop, and won't work for me since the animations will change for every iteration

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking for then. Where is that "next iteration" in your code that changes the animations?

Comment: on every iteration the variables _from_ and _to_ change with values coming from an array (width,height,top,left).

Comment: And how are these iterations timed? Or do you just run them together and expect them to be queued as in jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. They happen onclick, when I click on one item all other items should animate in a certain way, when I click on another item, all shall animate on a different way and so forth.

Comment: Ahh. And it works only… for the first click? You might also edit these things into the question :-)

Comment: exactly, for the first click

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it just by adding a setTimeout(0) to call the animation after the animation name was set to none.

Here's the fixed code http://jsfiddle.net/kR384/3/:

```
function resetAndRun(o){
    one.style.webkitAnimationName = "none";
    …
    ten.style.webkitAnimationName = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){o.animateBox();}, 0); 
}
```

I hope it's useful for someone.