# More than one time click function is not working without reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onitemclicklistener

1. Click function is working properly.
2. But if we click the hand img more than one time it is not working when page is reloaded, below is the code.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#container .like a img").click(function(){
           $("#container .balloons a img").addClass("anima");
           });
       });
   ```
3. I want more than one click will be work, please solve the problem.
4. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/n3no4759/

Comment: The answer to this question provides good insight - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797675/how-do-i-re-trigger-a-webkit-css-animation-via-javascript

Answer (score 3):

check this out

```
$("#container .like a img").on("click", function(){
    $("#container .balloons a img").addClass("anima").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend' , function(event){   
        $(this).removeClass("anima");
    });

});
```

here the working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/muhaimincs/n3no4759/14/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't remove `anima` class. You can use `setTimeout` function to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container .like a img").click(function(){
        $("#container .balloons a img").addClass("anima");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#container .balloons a img").removeClass("anima");
        }, 500)
        });
    });
```